# How can I display a nested list inline with its parent list?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a nav bar that I would like to run side by side. What I would like is that the "ABC Categories" portion *begin* inline along with the rest of the nav bar, with the "ABC Categories" nav bar being it's own height (~450px), moved down 450px and the regular inline sidebar being it's own height (~50px).

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GePyxL)

Thank you for any help.

```css
#low-nav {
 background-color: #0099CC;
 display: grid;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 16px;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 14px;
}
#low-nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
#low-nav ul a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 25px;
}
#low-nav #side-nav{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="low-nav">
 <ul>
  <a href="">
   <li>
    <ul id="side-nav">
     <li>ABC Categories</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
     <li>Stuff</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
  <a href="">
   <li>Stuff</li>
  </a>
 
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to provide a sketch or ascii diagram of the desired outcome. :)